# Escaping unquoted attributes

Tags: javascript, security, xss

With quoted attributes, I already know the solution.

```
function encodeForHTML(str){
    return str
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#x27;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;');
}
```

How about unquoted one? Which characters must be escaped beside those 6 characters? And how can I implement it in JS?

Comment: What if `attribute=value1 value2`. It would be invalid. So, you should try to use quote: `attribute="value1 value2"`

Comment: [`/[-_\u00A0-\u10FFFF]/`](https://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the W3 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted), the characters not allowed in unquoted attribute values are """, "'", "=", ">", "<", or "`" and the literal space character. (Oh, and the attribute value cannot be the empty string, either.)

I think the only additions to what you already have are the equal sign, back-quote, and space. Note that you can also eliminate the forward slash ("/") from your list; it doesn't need encoding.